# Law of Exponents proof for Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Show that, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ is an Abelian group, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all  $a$ and $b$ in $G$.

Proof:

For positive $n$, we know the statement is true for $n=1$ by $(ab)^1=ab=a^1b^1=ab\space\checkmark$. Now we will proceed by induction on $n$, assuming the statement is true for $n=k$ to show it is true for $n=k+1$.

Letting $z=ab$,

$$\begin{align}
z^{k+1}&=z^kz^1\\
&=(ab)^kz\\
&=(a^kb^k)z\\
&=a^kb^kab\\
&=a^kb^kba \\
&=a^kb^{k+1}a \\
&=aa^kb^{k+1} \\
&=a^{k+1}b^{k+1}.\checkmark
\end{align}$$

For negative $n$, we know the statement is true for $n=-1$ since $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ since $G$ is Abelian. Now we will proceed by induction on $n$, assuming the statement to be true for $n=-k$ to show that the statement is true for $n=-k-1$.

Letting $z=ab,$

$$\begin{align}
z^{-k-1}&=z^{-k}z^{-1}\\
&=(ab)^{-k}z^{-1}\\
 &=(a^{-k}b^{-k})(ab)^{-1} \\
&=(a^{-k}b^{-k})(b^{-1}a^{-1}) \\
&=(a^{-k}b^{-k-1})a^{-1} \\
&=a^{-1}(a^{-k}b^{-k-1}) \\
&=a^{-k-1}b^{-k-1}.\space\checkmark
\end{align}$$

Hence the statement is true for all integers.

Is this a Valid proof? Thanks!

Comment: $(ab)^k = (ab)(ab)$ which is equivalent to $a^kb^k,$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$ if and only if for all $a, b \in G$, $ab=ba$, that is, if and only if G is abelian.  So you need to justify your initial workings with the fact that $G$ is abelian, in your work following "letting $z = ab$"

Comment: So by saying after the lines "Letting z=ab," in both parts, "since G is abelian..." and the rest of the proof is correct? I think I forgot to add that explicitly even though I was using that fact the whole time.

Comment: Indeed, livingtolearn, that's all you'd need to do, and the rest of the proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

*As @Namaste points out in the comments  . . .*

Yes, you proof is valid, provided you mention that the group $G$ is abelian in all the right places.